# Selenium C# Firefox won't open URL when I use custom profile

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

I have this weird error in selenium webdriver in C# where it will only open a URL if I'm not using a profile. This code below does **not** work.

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.AddArguments("-profile", profilePath);

IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com"); //Opens Firefox (with profile) but not URL, times out
```

Meanwhile this code works.

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();


IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://example.com"); //Opens Firefox and URL no problem.
```

I tried using Firefox's *-url* launch argument, and then it opened the URL, even with a profile, but it timed out and didn't complete the rest of the code.

Comment: did you fix it?

Comment: I forgot about this, but looking at my code it looks like I solved it.
Here's my current code:

profile = selenium.webdriver.FirefoxProfile(profile_path)
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get(url)

Comment: I tried many things and none of them worked after hours fighting and found this: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1058#issuecomment-415141141, seems to be a bug in geckodriver